# Sending a keystroke to multiple OpenGL GUIs

Tags: opengl

I have a bash script that start X times the same process in the background. Each of these processes is mostly GUI that uses OpenGL.

I would like to send to each running background process a keystroke (such as Ctrl + Shift + A), so that the code in the background process captures that key combination and executes it (just as if it was pressed by the user in the GUI).

I haven't found a way to do that. The only I could get close to it is to use some interprocess communication, like pipes, but it requires modifying my background processes. It would only allow me to hook up the pipe to whatever the keystroke executes.

Most solutions involve injecting to the focused window, but here X GUI apps get launched, I have their PIDs but I have to send the same keystroke to all of them. Is there anyway to simulate the keystrokes although multiple GUI are running at the same time from my shell script please?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, and I kinda doubt there is one, but this has nothing to do with either Bash or TTYs, so I'm editing it to remove those tags.  This is a complicated problem to solve.  There are some GUI automation tools out there that are used for testing, but I doubt any of them can handle multicasting.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I was thinking the same afterwards. I think I'll go with a pipe approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [XSendEvent](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSendEvent.html) of Xlib to send other windows synthetic input events. You can also use the Xcb library's [xcb_send_event](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/xcb_send_event.3.xhtml) for the same purpose.

However since I expect you want to easily script it, you'll probably use Xlib, for example using the Python Xlib bindings.

With those you can

- enumerate all windows
- select your OpenGL windows
- send the synthetic keypress event to them

Note that X11 allows you to register custom events, so you could such as well.